# ArangoDB 2 GraphML

Tags: arangodb, graphml, pyarango

Is there a way to export ArangoDB-Graphs to GraphML?

I'm accessing the database using pyArango. [arangoexport](https://www.arangodb.com/2017/02/arangoexport-tool-exporting-data-arangodb/) seems to focus on JSON(L) only.

Answer (score 1):

You can try converting your ArangoDB graph to a NetworkX graph and then use the Networkx API for the conversion.
You can convert your ArangoDB graph to a networkx graph using the networkx adapter. You need to describe the vertex and edge collections of your ArangoDB graph using a dictionary. See the section "Connect ArangoDB and NetworkX" in :
https://github.com/arangoml/networkx-adapter/blob/master/examples/ArangoDB_NetworkxAdapter.ipynb
for details.
Once you have the networkx graph, covert it to graphML using:
https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/readwrite/generated/networkx.readwrite.graphml.write_graphml.html

Comment: Hey, thanks for the resources! The first link I got on the NetworkX page was rather useless, yours does help (I had this one: https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/readwrite/graphml.html)